# Error handling in JavaScript using try catch statement

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I am looking for handling JS errors using `try-catch` statement, but its not alerting the Error the way I supposed it has to pop up error. Let me know what I am doing wrong here in the code.

Code testing browser - `FireFox`

**Code** -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
document.write(parseInt("15");  // Broken code
}
catch(e) {
alert("Error " + e.description);
}
</script>
```

When I `firebug` the code its only showing the error in the try block that was all supposed to be but no `alert` pop up that ss what I am expecting.

Site reference I made before asking -

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_error_handling.htm

[Error handling in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942798/error-handling-in-javascript)  [Answer is referring to the same above mentioned URL]

Comment: You can't catch syntax errors.

Comment: @Juhana so is there any way in JS Like what we did in php ex- check mysql conn established or not ..if not throw error..something like that ?

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526129/is-it-possible-to-programatically-catch-javascript-syntaxerrors

Comment: Runtime errors that can be caught with try-catch.

Comment: @Juhana In the duplicate link you mentioned referring to use eval() is it really required even for this simple stuff..no other way??

Comment: You can't catch syntax errors because the interpreter/compiler can't understand the code. It doesn't know where the `catch()` is and what to do with it. So yes, `eval()` is the only choice AFAIK.

Comment: @Juhana Thx for the answer and link..I think its ok to stick with FIREBUG instead of controlling and alerting errors in JS way :)