# Catching SyntaxError caused by bad JS loaded via jQuery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Javascript control that loads a page containing HTML and some Javascript needed only by that page.

Initially I operated under [YAGNI](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)/KISS assumptions and kept all the Javascript in a single large `functions.js` file; but now the number of pages has grown, and moreover, several of them are variations that need slightly different instantiations of the same functions.

So I would find it very useful to be able to write

```
 <div>...<button id="object123">Don't click me!</button>... </div>
 <script>
     $('#object123').on('click', function(){
         alert("I said not to click!");
     });
 </script>
```

and load it with

```
 // All error checking omitted for clarity
 $(divSelector).load('page-with-object-123.html');
```

Given that I already have checks in place for uniqueness of IDs et cetera, a problem arises if **the script contains a syntax error**. In that case of course execution stops, but what's more, I get an error *inside jQuery* (the point where the `.load` executes the `<script>` tag). So it is not immediate to track down the error to the originating HTML.

I *am* able to get the error (for that matter the only syntax error in my scripts is now intentional), but I'd like to catch it in order to handle it gracefully.

I have tried the obvious with `try/catch`

```
try {
    $(divSelector).load(sourceHTML);
} catch (err) {
    alert("An error occurred in " + sourceHTML);
}
```

but the error isn't caught. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526129/is-it-possible-to-programatically-catch-javascript-syntaxerrors) would suggest it should have been, unless jQuery does something weird to the try/catch mechanism.

I have then tried using `window.onerror` as suggested by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506444/catch-a-javascript-error-in-an-external-script-file). In its default incarnation **it works** (i.e. I define the onerror callback globally).

At that point I tried to effect the change in the function body itself, and have the handler restored once it was no longer needed.

While it tantalizingly *appeared* to have worked once (possiby because I was looking at an older, global version of the code due to client caching), I can't seem to make it work.

I *was* careful <sup><sup>after the mandatory facepalm</sup></sup> to restore the handler only *after* the call had been really issued.

```js
/**
 * Effect a call 
 * @param string    op*        command
 * @param dict      data       data to send
 * @param callable  callback   function to be called on success 
 * @param callable  onError    function to be called on failure
 */
function poster(op, data, callback, onError) {
    // Save handler
    var origHandler = window.onerror;
    // Install new error handler
    window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {
        alert(message + "\n" + url + "\n" + lineNumber);
        return true;
    };
    $.post(
        ajaxUrl,
        $.extend({ op: op }, data),
        function (responseText, statusText, jqXHR) {
            // Evaluate the response for server error notifications
            var todo = jqBadResponse(responseText) ? onError : callback;
            // Edit: try using onerror to watch also callbacks.
            // window.onerror = origHandler;
            todo && todo(responseText);
            // Restore error handler
            window.onerror = origHandler;
        }
    ).fail(function(jqXHR, title) { // Outer failure.
        // Restore error handler
        window.onerror = origHandler; 
        jqCheckFail(jqXHR, title); // Notify of the error
    });
}
```

I know [what my basic problem is](http://www.xradiograph.com/interference/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/programming_wrong.png)... what I *don't* know, is *where* it is in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual side-effect of carefully checking the requirements for posting a sensible question on Stack Overflow -- *you stumble on the answer*.

As I said, I *used* a function to load a HTML into a DIV. But now with the above function *I do that differently*. The actual assignment is no longer done by jQuery in `.load()` *but by my own callback*.

And jQuery will interpret the Javascript and throw a SyntaxError **in the `.html()` call**, not in the `.load()` call anymore. Inside the `.load` function, the loaded HTML code is just a string, and whatever syntax errors it contains are ignored.

It's when I tell jQuery to consider that string as HTML and place it in the DOM that the exception is thrown. This *does* happen while I'm inside the `.post` function, but it happens farther down in the scope.

I still don't quite understand why the outer `try {}` failed to catch it, but I'm reasonably confident this may have to do with the fact that

```
try (
    var a = ...*some Promise whose payload will be executed sometime in the near future*...
} catch (e) {
    // Here I catch the error and there is no error;
    // the Promise did promise the impossible, but that
    // offer hasn't been picked up yet.
}
...
// NOW finally the Promise executes and throws. But I'm no longer inside
// a try/catch block.
```

Indeed if I place the try/catch in a synchronous block

```
poster(
    'form',
    {
        code:  ...,
        id:    ...
    },
    function (responseText) {
        try {
            $('#details').html(responseText.data.html);
        } catch(e) {
            alert("GOTCHA");                
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
);
```

the exception is correctly caught.